# What does "Vertex-transitivity" tell us about an arbitrary graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I know the formal definition, i.e. , for any arbitrary graph *G*,

$\forall v_i,v_j\in V(G)\, \exists g \in Auto(G) \, s.t. g(v_i)=v_j$

But what does it mean in a broader sense?

Comment: It means there is a pleasant symmetry to the graph. Consider the graph of a soccer ball, for example, where every vertex belongs to two hexagonal faces and a pentagonal face, and the vertices are interchangeable by spinning the ball.

Comment: So back to our formal definition, what you said means that for each two vertices, I could find an automorphism,namely, a rotation from one vertex exactly toward the other? @Théophile

Comment: Yes, that's right. So it formalizes the idea of "you can't tell the difference between the vertices". An $n$-cycle is also vertex transitive: pick any $u,v \in V$, and there is an obvious automorphism sending $u$ to $v$. To put it another way, there are no "special" vertices. A star, for example, where one central vertex $w$ is connected to a number of leaves, is not vertex transitive; you can easily distinguish $w$ from the leaves (which is an informal way of saying that no automorphism sends $w$ to a leaf).

Comment: Compare also to *edge transitivity*, which is similar but (of course) applies to edges instead of vertices. A soccer ball is not edge transitive because there are two kinds of edges: either both endpoints are on the same pentagon, or they are on different pentagons. An $n$-cycle, on the other hand, is edge transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a graph $X=(V(X),E(X))$ is vertex transitive, then we can talk about some obvious things.

- Graph $X$ is regular.(converse is not true Eg: Frucht Graph)
- $Aut(X)$ is non-trivial.
- Graph $X$ is symmetric.
- Graph $X$ is locally similar, that means by looking at the vertices we can actually observe that locally they are same.

For example, Cayley Graph $X=(G,C)$ where $G$ is any group and $C$ is any subset of G which doesn't contain the identity and it's closed under inverse. Cayley graphs are regular and by construction, we can find a subgroup which is acting transitively on $X$.

Another important example is $J(5,2,0)$ Petersen graph. Here $S_5$ acts transitively on the vertex set{ which is nothing but the set of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ of size 2. }.

Answer (score 2):

Its very similar to what homogeneity means in  topological spaces.

Basically it means that if I am sitting in one of the vertices and I want to tell Steve which vertex I am at while on the phone, I am gonna be totally screwed, because the graph looks the same from every vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Vertex transitive graphs are completely symmetric in the same way as the surface of a sphere is, every node has *all* the same properties as every other.

Graphs can be used to show group structure, for example:

[image: diagram]

This shows a dihedral symmetry group. It is the direct/cartesian multiplication of two simpler (sub) groups.

Note that (as a graph) it is also the direct multiplication of two vertex transitive graphs, and so it is also vertex transitive.

Moving the identity element `e` on the above diagram and relabelling the rest of the graph doesn't change any of the resulting group structure, any of the groups properties/uses, `abab` is still `e`, it's all still the same object.